# Java writing to multiple array lists using for loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

Im trying to achieve this in java... basically looping through 6 people then getting them to roll 100 random numbers,
Just trying to loop through the array list names more efficiently rather than having 6 loops for the different people. Any help appreciated.

```
int min = 1;
int max = 6;
int range = (max - min + 1);
ArrayList person1 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList person2 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList person3 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList person4 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList person5 = new ArrayList();
ArrayList person6 = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 1; i <=6; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <100; j++) {
        int rand = (int) (Math.random() * range) + min;
        //            System.out.print(rand + ", ");
        String person = "person" + i;
        System.out.println(person);
        person.add(rand);
            
    }
    
}

System.out.println(person1);
System.out.println(person2);
System.out.println(person3);
System.out.println(person4);
System.out.println(person5);
System.out.println(person6);
```

Comment: It would be easier if, instead of 6 separate `ArrayList`s, you used an array of `ArrayList`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Federico's comment, you can loop over an array (or List) of `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList[] persons = new ArrayList[6];

for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
    ArrayList<Integer> person = new ArrayList<>(100);
    
    for(int j=0; j<100; j++) {
        int rand = (int) (Math.random() * range) + min;
        //            System.out.print(rand + ", ");
        person.add(rand);
    }
    persons.add(person);
    
    System.out.println(person);
}
```

Please note that this involves a lot of auto boxing (implicit conversion from `int` to `Integer`), so if the 100 count is fixed, but the number of people may increase, it may become more efficient to use `int[]` instead of `ArrayList` to store the random numbers.

**If you like streams**, you can also do this:

```
List<List<Integer>> persons = IntStream.range(0,6)
        .mapToObj(i -> 
                  IntStream.range(0,100)
                            .map(j -> (int) (Math.random() * range) + min)
                            .mapToObj(Integer::valueOf)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()) //this is the list of 100 random numbers
                )
        .collect(Collectors.toList()) //to produce the list of 6 person lists
        ;
//print, return, do anything
persons.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Explanation**:

`IntStream.range(0,6)` produces a `Stream` of ints from 0 inclusive to 6 exclusive, i.e. `0,1,2,3,4,5`.
We use `mapToObj` to turn each of these into a list using a `mapper` (`i -> ...`), which we finally `collect` into a new list.

Inside the mapper, we use another `IntStream` to produce the 100 random values, which again we collect into a `List`.